# Proper format of a Google Drive API multipart/mixed batch request using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, httprequest, multipart

I am using Javascript (in the Google Apps Script Editor) to make HTTP requests to the Google Drive API.

I've successfully made individual calls to the API, so I know my Oauth 2 works, but now I'm working on making a batch request.

I will loop through each file, and make 2 API calls per file.

My request:

```
var newOwnerEmail = 'archive@test.com';
var newEditorEmail = 'admin@test.com';
var fileIds = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const boundary = 'testboundaryname';
const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

var multipartRequestBody = '';

for (var i = 0; i < fileIds.length; i++) {

  var fileId = fileIds[i];

  var resource1 = { role: "owner", type: "user", value: newOwnerEmail };

  var requestBody = {};
  requestBody.path = '/drive/v2/files/' + fileId + '/permissions';
  requestBody.method = 'POST';
  requestBody.contentType = 'application/json';
  requestBody.payload = JSON.stringify(resource1);
  requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = true;

  multipartRequestBody += delimiter;
  multipartRequestBody += 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n';
  multipartRequestBody += JSON.stringify(requestBody);

  var resource2 = { role: "writer", type: "user", value: newEditorEmail };

  requestBody.payload = JSON.stringify(resource2);

  multipartRequestBody += delimiter;
  multipartRequestBody += 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n';
  multipartRequestBody += JSON.stringify(requestBody);

}

multipartRequestBody += close_delim;

var batchUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch';

var batchRequestBody = {};
batchRequestBody.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() };
batchRequestBody.method = 'POST';
batchRequestBody.contentType = 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"';
batchRequestBody.body = multipartRequestBody;
batchRequestBody.muteHttpExceptions = true;

try {

  var batchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(batchUrl, batchRequestBody);

  Logger.log(batchResponse);
```

`multipartRequestBody` ends up being a string that looks like this:

```
 --testboundary
 Content-Type: application/json
 {"method":"POST","contentType":"application/json","payload":"{\"role\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"user\",\"value\":\"archive@test.com\"}","muteHttpExceptions":false}
 --testboundary
 Content-Type: application/json
 {"method":"POST","contentType":"application/json","payload":"{\"role\":\"writer\",\"type\":\"user\",\"value\":\"admin@test.com\"}","muteHttpExceptions":false}
 --testboundary
 Content-Type: application/json
 {"method":"POST","contentType":"application/json","payload":"{\"role\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"user\",\"value\":\"archive@test.com\"}","muteHttpExceptions":false}
 --testboundary
 Content-Type: application/json
 {"method":"POST","contentType":"application/json","payload":"{\"role\":\"writer\",\"type\":\"user\",\"value\":\"admin@test.com\"}","muteHttpExceptions":false}
 --testboundary
 Content-Type: application/json
 {"method":"POST","contentType":"application/json","payload":"{\"role\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"user\",\"value\":\"archive@test.com\"}","muteHttpExceptions":false}
 --testboundary
 Content-Type: application/json
 {"method":"POST","contentType":"application/json","payload":"{\"role\":\"writer\",\"type\":\"user\",\"value\":\"admin@test.com\"}","muteHttpExceptions":false}
 --testboundary--
```

I ran `UrlFetchApp.getRequest()` to see what was being sent to the server, and it's this:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "X-Forwarded-For": “(our external IP address)“
  },
  "method": "post",
  "payload": "\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"owner\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"archive@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"writer\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"admin@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"owner\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"archive@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"writer\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"admin@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"owner\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"archive@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"writer\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"admin@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"owner\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"archive@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"writer\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"admin@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"owner\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"archive@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n{\"method\":\"POST\",\"contentType\":\"application/json\",\"payload\":\"{\\\"role\\\":\\\"writer\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"user\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"admin@test.com\\\"}\",\"muteHttpExceptions\":false}\r\n--testboundary--",
  "followRedirects": true,
  "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
  "useIntranet": false,
  "contentType": "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"testboundary\"",
  "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/batch"
}
```

I get this response:

```
Unsupported number format: --
```

There's definitely something wrong with the content of the request, but it's difficult to determine what it is, given that there's such little documentation for creating batch requests using Javascript.

The only documentation I could find is [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/batch), but the example is language-independent/hypothetical.

Then I found [this example](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js), which seems to use a Google API client library, which I can't use in Apps Script.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I didn't realize what the suggested edit was, and then I saw that it was rejected but I accidentally approved it. I added the javascript tag because I feel it's important to clarify in this case that I'm using Javascript because the official documentation for Google APIs usually just has sample code for Python, Ruby, Java, etc. but rarely ever Javascript. In my case I need to be able to use Javascript, and I'm having trouble resolving this issue because there is almost no examples on the Internet or similar question on SO of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you;show the output of a UrlFetchApp.getRequest?

Comment: The output is above - the part where I wrote "I get this response:" (the `Bad Request` and `Error 400`)

Comment: I mean the getRequest results. It will show the details of your outgoing request.

Comment: Wow, sorry about that. I didn't even realize the UrlFetchApp.getRequest method existed! That's awesome. Anyway, I updated my question with the results, and also running that method showed me that `.params` and `.body` should actually both just be `.payload`. After changing them to `payload` I got a different result.

Comment: I would start with doing a batch consisting of a single item.

The contentType in the Payload might be content-Type, because onyl UrlFetchApp uses it without a - ... 

MuteHttpExceptions should not be in payload netier I think.

Actually I am doing this for myself in the upcoming week so I will stay in touch. 

PS 
change ownership can only be done by the owner.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try those suggestions when I get to the office. As for the auth, I'm the super admin of my Google Apps domain, and I'm using "Domain-wide Delegation of Authority" with a service account, which allows me to "impersonate" the user (gets a valid oauth 2 token for that user from the service (`service.getAccessToken()`) I've tested that specific API call alone without batching and it works.

Comment: I no longer need to figure this out, Google just today released a [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/).